# jquery with or without extend keyword

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me any difference between these two kinds of extend function? thanks.

```
$.fn.alertWhileClick= function() {
   alert($(this).val());
}


$.fn.extend({
    alertWhileClick:function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Hi , edhedges, this one is extending `$` or `Jquery` object method. for example `$.alertWhileClick()`, thanks.

Comment: @Joe, what makes you think there is a difference between these two forms?

Comment: @Frederic I am not familiar with the js , I just can't understand why they got the same result .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two forms are equivalent. The first one adds a method to jQuery's prototype via assignment, the second does that through a call to `$.fn.extend()`, which is the same method as [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

The documentation is actually a little misleading here, since it says:

> If only one argument is supplied to `$.extend()`, this means the target
>   argument was omitted. In this case, the jQuery object itself is
>   assumed to be the target.

But what actually happens is something more like:

> If only one argument is supplied to `$.extend()`, this means the target
>   argument was omitted. In this case, **the object `$.extend()` is applied to (i.e. the object bound to `this` within the method)** is
>   assumed to be the target.

So, calling `$.extend()` with a single argument extends `$`, and calling `$.fn.extend()` with a single argument extends `$.fn`.

The relevant parts of the source code say:

```
jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {

    // [...]

    // extend jQuery itself if only one argument is passed
    if ( length === i ) {
        target = this;  // Note: 'this', not 'jQuery'.
        --i;
    }

    // [...]
};
```

Comment: the answer is handsome like you !